# How many bit strings of length $5$ do not have consecutive $1$'s?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

How many bit strings **of length 5 do *not* have consecutive 1's**?

I'm trying to think of a way to calculate how many ways we can arrange a string of length 5 starting with the first position (or index).

I feel like in this case we would use a **permutation** because order matters. I also believe repetition is not allowed (hence no consecutive 1's) here? Please correct me if I'm going about this wrong.

Comment: You have to repeat if you only have two possible options but five places you must fill.

Comment: This type of problem has been dealt with a number of times on MSE. For length $5$, a careful organized listing is feasible. I think you will find there are $13$. For a couple of more general ideas, you could look at [this recent question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1822239/combinatorics-color-a-wall-such-that-not-two-neighbored-slots-have-the-same-col/1822273#1822273)

Comment: Repetitions are mandatory so permutations are not a good idea.  Strings should nearly always be lists.  In this case you can count the number of strings with 5 1s (0), 4 1s (0), 3 1s (1, do you know why) 2 1s (??) and 1 1 (5; for obvious reasons).

Answer (score 1):

We can solve the problem recursively.

Let $a_n$ denote the number of permissible bit strings of length $n$.

A bit string of length $1$ cannot have two consecutive ones.  Since there are two ways to fill the digit, $a_1 = 2$.

The only bit string of length $2$ that has two consecutive ones is $11$.  Since there are two ways to fill each of the two digits in the bit string, $a_2 = 2 \cdot 2 - 1 = 3$.

Any permissible bit string of length $n + 1$ that ends in $0$ can be formed by by appending a $0$ to the end of a permissible bit string of length $n$, of which there are $a_n$.

For a bit string of length $n + 1$ to end in a $1$, the entry in the $n$th position must be a zero.  Thus, any permissible bit string of length $n + 1$ that ends in a $1$ can be formed by appending the bit string $01$ to a permissible bit string of length $n - 1$, of which there are $a_{n - 1}$.

Thus, we have the recurrence relation
\begin{align*}
a_1 & = 2\\
a_2 & = 3\\
a_{n + 1} & = a_n + a_{n - 1}, n \geq 2
\end{align*}
You can use the recurrence relation to determine $a_5$, the number of bit strings of length $5$ that do not have two consecutive ones.

Comment: These strings are often called **Fibbinaries**, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Listing all binary strings of length $5$ satisfying the condition should work for a problem of this small a size.  Or, you can find the number of binary strings of length $5$ that have consecutive 1's and subtract that number from $32$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are two $1's$ , and so three $0's$,
the two $1's$ can be inserted at the uparrows in $\binom42$ ways, as shown under:
$\uparrow 0 \uparrow 0 \uparrow 0\uparrow\;\;$ which generalizes to $\binom{n-k+1}{k}$ for $k\;\; 1's$

For $n = 5$, $k$ can be $\le3$, thus $$\text{answer}=\sum_{k=0}^3 \binom{6-k}{k}= 13$$